# How to paraller make phone call from JAIN SLEE B2BUA server?

Tags: sip, rhino, jain-slee

I'm newbie to JAIN SLEE + SIP and I have a task to write simple B2BUA server on Rhino SDK. I have an example were client can register and make phone call to other clients. My task is to change this example to:

- Client A make phone calls to B2BUA server to some virtual number
- B2BUA server parallel make phone calls to clients which are registered to this virtual number so their phone ring.
- When some client will pick up the phone then send *+200 OK* to the B2BUA server
- B2BUA server automatically redirect it to client A so this pair of clients will talk
- And the same time B2BUA send CANCEL to others clients

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you just described what you need to do what else :) ?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261 -> page 11-12

```
                 atlanta.com  . . . biloxi.com
             .      proxy              proxy     .
           .                                       .
   Alice's  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Bob's
  softphone                                        SIP Phone
     |                |                |                |
     |    INVITE F1   |                |                |
     |--------------->|    INVITE F2   |                |
     |  100 Trying F3 |--------------->|    INVITE F4   |
     |<---------------|  100 Trying F5 |--------------->|
     |                |<-------------- | 180 Ringing F6 |
     |                | 180 Ringing F7 |<---------------|
     | 180 Ringing F8 |<---------------|     200 OK F9  |
     |<---------------|    200 OK F10  |<---------------|
     |    200 OK F11  |<---------------|                |
     |<---------------|                |                |
     |                       ACK F12                    |
     |------------------------------------------------->|
     |                   Media Session                  |
     |<================================================>|
     |                       BYE F13                    |
     |<-------------------------------------------------|
     |                     200 OK F14                   |
     |------------------------------------------------->|
     |                                                  |
```

Proxy works more or less As B2BUA, very simple B2B.

YOu need to copy SDP between answers etc.